# Cache web forms in client side

Tags: caching, webforms

is it possible to cache form contents on client side? Like maintaining state even if the form is un-saved and the user moves to a new page then returns back to the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be by using Javascript/AJAX to talk to the server, saving each form field as the user went off it. Then, when you load the page, you'd see if there was any content for each form already saved.

Comment: i'm looking at a number of forms in a page (since we have tabs to separate them). Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You could use Javascript to set and get sessions, but honestly it'd probably better to just use the server-side to manage it. Shouldn't take that much time. (You could store it in the session array, with each form having a unique ID and fields inside it.)